# не запускается service в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, gunicorn, systemd

делал так , как было в туториале на DigitalOcean
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-gunicorn

создал файл с расширением .service и впихнул туда это

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

ввел sudo sysytemctl daemon-reload , systemctl start myproject,systemctl enable myproject

после этого прописал статус и получил такую ошибку

```
Jan 10 16:35:44 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve myproject.
Jan 10 16:35:44 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-fra1-01 systemd[11584]: myproject.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Jan 10 16:35:44 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-fra1-01 systemd[11584]: myproject.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/user/myproject/.virtualenvs/myp
Jan 10 16:35:44 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: myproject.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 10 16:35:44 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: myproject.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

upd : service заработал , но приложение не работает , в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте лучше

```
EnvironmentFile=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/activate
```